# Python форматирование строк по данным словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь:

```
dict_a = {
    'a': {
        '1': 'd',
        '2': 'f',
        '3': 'h',
        ..... и т.д.
    },
    'b': {
        '1': 'c',
        '2': 'j',
        '3': 'u',
        ..... и т.д.
    },
    .... и т.д.
}
```

Нужно форматировать строку:

```
print("a1: %d, a2: %d, ..., b1: %d, b2: %, ... % ???)
```

И мне надо заполнить это данными из словаря.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться генератором, объединив результат с помощью метода `join`.

***Пример:***

```py
dict_a = {'a': {'1': 'd', '2': 'f', '3': 'h'}, 'b': {'1': 'c', '2': 'j', '3': 'u'}}

s = ', '.join(f'{w}{n}: {dict_a[w][n]}' for w in dict_a for n in dict_a[w])
print(s)
```

***stdout:***

```py
a1: d, a2: f, a3: h, b1: c, b2: j, b3: u
```